# addition in my android calculator doesn't work fully

Tags: android, eclipse, calculator

I have made an android calculator. Though it isn't completely as a normal calculator. In normal calculators, when we add up two numbers, suppose 5+5 and we click any of these, /*-+=, the number sums up and the new arithmetic logic is implemented on the result. Though it doesn't work for me. Can someone please tell me what changes shall I make in my code?
Thank you. :)

```
package com.example.asd;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Typeface font1, font2;

TextView tv1;
private EditText Scr; //textbox screen
private float NumberBf; //Save screen before pressing button operation;
private String Operation;
private ButtonClickListener btnClick;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    font1=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "digits.ttf");
    Scr=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Scr.setTypeface(font1);
    font2=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "alexbrush.TTF");
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv1.setTypeface(font2);
    Scr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Scr.setEnabled(false);
    btnClick = new ButtonClickListener();
    int idList[] = {R.id.button0,R.id.button7, R.id.button1, R.id.button8,R.id.button9,R.id.button4,
            R.id.button5,R.id.button6,R.id.button,R.id.button2,R.id.button3,R.id.buttonDot,
            R.id.buttonMul,R.id.buttonDiv,R.id.buttonAdd,R.id.buttonSub,R.id.buttonC,
            R.id.buttonEq, R.id.buttonSqrt, R.id.buttonsquare, R.id.buttonNp
    };

    for(int id:idList){
        View v = (View) findViewById(id);
        v.setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void mMath(String str){
    NumberBf = Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString()); //save the screen
    Operation = str; //save operation
    Scr.setText("0"); //Clear screen
}

public void getKeyboard(String str){
    String ScrCurrent = Scr.getText().toString();
    if(ScrCurrent.equals("0"))
        ScrCurrent = "";
    ScrCurrent += str;
    Scr.setText(ScrCurrent);
}

public void mResult(){
    float NumAf = Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString());
    float result = 0;
    if(Operation.equals("+")){
        result = NumAf + NumberBf;
    }
    if(Operation.equals("-")){
        result = NumberBf - NumAf;
    }
    if(Operation.equals("*")){
        result = NumAf * NumberBf;
    }
    if(Operation.equals("/")){
        result = NumberBf / NumAf;
    }
    Scr.setText(String.format("%10d", result));
}

public void fnSqrt(){
    double Number = Double.parseDouble(Scr.getText().toString());
    Number = Math.sqrt(Number);
    Scr.setText(String.valueOf(Number));
}

public void fnSquare(){
    float Number1 = Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString());
    Number1 = pow(Number1, 2);
    Scr.setText(String.valueOf(Number1));
}

public void fnNp(){
    float Number = Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString());
    Number = Number*(-1);
    Scr.setText(String.valueOf(Number));
    }

//new class ButtonClickListener


private float pow(float number1, int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return number1*number1;
}

private class ButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener{
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonC: //Clear screen
                Scr.setText("0");
                NumberBf = 0;
                Operation = "";
                break;
            case R.id.buttonAdd: //function Add
                mMath("+");
                break;
            case R.id.buttonSub:
                mMath("-");
                break;
            case R.id.buttonMul:
                mMath("*");
                break;
            case R.id.buttonDiv:
                mMath("/");
                break;
            case R.id.buttonEq:
                mResult();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonSqrt:
                fnSqrt();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonNp:
                fnNp();
                break;    
            case R.id.buttonsquare:
                fnSquare();
                break;
            default:
                String numb = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
                getKeyboard(numb);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "it doesn't work for me" -- this is not a very useful description of your symptoms. Please edit your question to explain **completely and precisely** what this means. You may wish to consider reading other StackOverflow questions to see what sorts of information is needed in order to get assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This code works. I've done a parsing calculator in the past, which seems to be totally different. 
I suggest using a debugger , run in eclipse with the bug button, and when you get to the point where things go wrong, add a breakpoint in your event handling method. and step through using the step over button , and step into any methods that might have the bug. May need to do it a few times.

I needed to use the debugger to get the code below to work. Because it lets you change the operation e.g. pressing 3 + - 2  =    will give 1 ; the +/- button is not working yet because the code is simplified to look at the labels of the button, specifically the first character.

What I found with the debugger was :

1. when the last result was a float, and the next input is an integer, it didn't branch to the float op float part of the doOperation, because of improper nesting of sigDiff in an outer separate if block.
2. when the decimal point was entered, it was not registered, because the testing for setting the boolean currentNumberDecimal occurred before the first decimal point was processed, and should have occurred after the first decimal point is processed.

Also found that an integer divided by an integer has to be retested for whether the result is an integer or a float. Can't remember if the debugger found that for me.

```
package com.example.calc1;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Number lastNumber;
char lastOp;
char beforeLastOp;
char pendingOp;
private boolean currentNumberDecimal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void buttonPressed(View view) {
    Button b = (Button) view;
    Log.d("Buttons ", "pressed " + b);

    EditText edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    char ch = b.getText().length() > 0 ? b.getText().charAt(0) : 0;
    switch (ch) {
    case '=':
        doCalculation(edit1);
        edit1.setText(lastNumber.toString());
        lastOp = 0;
        beforeLastOp = 0;
        lastNumber = null;
        break;
    case '+':
    case '-':

    case '*':

    case '/':
        lastOp = ch;
        break;
    case 'A':
        edit1.getText().clear();
        lastNumber = null;
        lastOp = 0;
        break;

    }



    if ((ch == '.' || Character.isDigit(ch)) && lastOp != 0) {

        doCalculation(edit1);

        beforeLastOp = lastOp;
        lastOp = 0;
        edit1.getText().clear();

        currentNumberDecimal = ch == '.';
    }

    if ((ch == '.' && !currentNumberDecimal) || Character.isDigit(ch)) {
        edit1.getText().append(ch);
    }

    if (ch == '.' && !currentNumberDecimal)
        currentNumberDecimal = true;

}

private void doCalculation(EditText edit1) {
    String s = edit1.getText().toString();
    float f = Float.parseFloat(s);
    boolean sigDiff = true;
    try {
        float f2 = (float) Integer.parseInt(s);
        sigDiff = Math.abs(f - f2) > Float.MIN_NORMAL;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        sigDiff = true;
    }

    if (lastNumber == null && !sigDiff) {
        lastNumber = Integer.parseInt(s);
    } else if (lastNumber == null && sigDiff) {
        lastNumber = f;
    } else if (!sigDiff && lastNumber.getClass().equals(Integer.class)) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
        switch (beforeLastOp) {
        case '+':
            lastNumber = lastNumber.intValue() + i;
            break;
        case '-':
            lastNumber = lastNumber.intValue() - i;
            break;
        case '*':
            lastNumber = lastNumber.intValue() * i;
            break;
        case '/':
            Number n = lastNumber.intValue() / i;
            float f3 = lastNumber.floatValue() / i;

            if (Math.abs(f3 - n.floatValue()) > Float.MIN_NORMAL) {
                lastNumber = f3;
            } else {
                lastNumber = n;
            }

            break;
        default:
            lastNumber = i;
            break;

        }
    } else {
        switch (beforeLastOp) {
        case '+':
            lastNumber = lastNumber.floatValue() + f;
            break;
        case '-':
            lastNumber = lastNumber.floatValue() - f;
            break;
        case '*':
            lastNumber = lastNumber.floatValue() * f;
            break;
        case '/':
            lastNumber = lastNumber.floatValue() / f;
            break;
        default:
            lastNumber = f;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: pow should be Math.pow( number1, i)  , although i can be a double.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, what about

```
public void mMath(String str){
  if (Operation != "" && Operation != null)
    mResult();
  NumberBf = Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString()); //save the screen

  Operation = str; //save operation
  Scr.setText("0"); //Clear screen
}
```